# Angular-cli compilation was successful, but error occured

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run `npm run ng`, compilation successes, but following error occur, and browser shows `Not found` message.

```
[rendered]                                                                                                             
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.                                                                                         
(node:31294) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exited with code 3                                                    
at ChildProcess.cp.once.code (/home/itadmin/my- 
website/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build- 
angular/node_modules/opn/index.js:84:13)                                                                                                          
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)                                                                                
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)                                                                                 
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)                                                                        
at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)                                                           
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)                                                                                       
at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:598:12)                                                                               
(node:31294) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without 
a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with 
.catch(). (rejection id: 14)                                                                                                               
(node:31294) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: @Aarsh Is it enough to post my `angular-cli.json` ? or what other details ?

Comment: As per error, its in your promise injection where you didn't use catch block so not needed angular-cli.json

Comment: to run an angular project locally you need to call ng serve command why you are using npm run ng?

Comment: @HrishikeshKale No in local its working, in production server when I want to build, it shows above error

Comment: for production build call ng build --prod also you can see proper documentation of this command on official site

Comment: @HrishikeshKale I also use `npm run ng:build`

Comment: @jones  and what is the error if you run npm run ng build ? can you please try running this?

Comment: @HrishikeshKale The same error.

Comment: Looks like it's a node modules issue? Try clean it and reinstall all packages on the server.

Comment: @wannadream I have already tried that.